# How to achieve stationarity for this type of time series using R?

Tags: r, model, time-series

This looks to me to have an exponential trend but I'm not completely sure how to approach this.

[image: Time Series]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the forecast package:

```
library(forecast)
no_diffs_to_stationary = ndiffs(df$px)
df$stationary_series <- c(rep(NA, no_diffs_to_stationary),
                          diff(df$px, no_diffs_to_stationary))
mean(df$stationary_series, na.rm = TRUE)
sd(df$stationary_series, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Data:

```
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out=1000)
df <- data.frame(x = x, px = dexp(x, rate=0.65))
```

Comment: @J. Lee Please accept my answer if it does what you require.